# Javascript - Leaflet - Ocultar/Mostrar marca en mapa pulsando botón

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Cómo hacer ocultar/mostrar marca en mapa al hacer clic en botón. No se si debería ser con display none, o de alguna manera quitar el addTo(map).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <script>

    let map = L.map('map').setView([40.310789, -1.970963],13.5)
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    maxZoom: 19
    }).addTo(map);

/*Marcas en plano:*/   
    var marker = L.marker([40.317900,-1.028754]).addTo(map).bindPopup("Playa").openPopup();
    var marker2 = L.marker([40.319581,-1.004942]).addTo(map).bindPopup("Rio").openPopup();

    </script>
```

Botones HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('playa').style.display='none'">Playa</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('rio').style.display='none'">Río</button>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ir a la sección de [marcadores de Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker) para encontrar más información de los métodos y eventos. Siguiendo la respuesta de "nomenostack"

> puedes crear una función que se active cuando se le da click al boton, luego usar los metodos de "addTo()" y "remove()" para adicionar y remover el marcador. Te sugiero leer la documentación, hay varios metodos y eventos para cada elemento de un mapa con Leaflet.

La solución se lo podria hacer de dos formas, una con botones dentro del mapa y otra con botones fuera del mapa. Aqui va el código:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<button class="btn btn-warning" id="quitar-marcadores">quitar marcadores</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="adicionar-marcadores">adicionar marcadores</button>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [18.9, -71.2],
        zoom: 8,
    });
    const tileURL = 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    L.tileLayer(tileURL).addTo(map);

    // ejemplo de creación y adición de marcadores
    datos = [
        { 'latitud': 19.01, 'longitud': -71.21 },
        { 'latitud': 19.29, 'longitud': -72.10 },
        { 'latitud': 19.05, 'longitud': -71.48 },
        { 'latitud': 19.15, 'longitud': -71.89 },
        { 'latitud': 19.00, 'longitud': -72.11 },
        // adicionar mas puntos geográficos aqui
    ];
    marcadores = [];
    for (var j=0; j<datos.length; j++) {
        marcadores[j] = L.marker([datos[j].latitud, datos[j].longitud]).addTo(map);  
    };


    //  ------------- Solución #1 --------------------
    document.getElementById('quitar-marcadores').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var n=0; n<marcadores.length; n++) {
            marcadores[n].remove(); // remover marcadores
        };
    });
    document.getElementById('adicionar-marcadores').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var n=0; n<marcadores.length; n++) {
            marcadores[n].addTo(map); // añadir marcadores
        };
    });


    //  ------------- Solución #2 --------------------
    var botonesControl = L.control({position: 'topright'}); // creación del contenedor de botones
    botonesControl.onAdd = function() {                     // creación de los botones
        var botones = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'class-css-botones');
        botones.innerHTML = `<buttom id="agregar-marcadores" class="btn btn-primary">agregar marcadores</buttom>`;
        botones.innerHTML += `<buttom id="remover-marcadores" class="btn btn-warning">remover marcadores</buttom>`;
        return botones;
    };
    botonesControl.addTo(map);   // adición del contenedor dentro del mapa
    document.getElementById('remover-marcadores').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var n=0; n<marcadores.length; n++) {
            marcadores[n].remove(); // remover marcadores
        };
    });
    document.getElementById('agregar-marcadores').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var n=0; n<marcadores.length; n++) {
            marcadores[n].addTo(map);   // añadir marcadores
        };
    });
</script>
```

Opcionalmente puedes añadir los cdn's de [Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) para que se vean bonitos.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Así es como se veria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, puedes modificar el código para quitar y adicionar otras geometrias como lineas, circulos, polígonos, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias giskan77. Si me permites la pregunta. ¿Permite Leaflet localización por dirección en vez de sólo por coordenada? (Ejemplo: Gran Vía 1, Barcelona). Un saludo.

Comment: No soy un experto en Leaflet, pero si, si se puede hacer eso. Pero tal vez la mejor y más práctica opción sea utilizar algun plugin, busca los plugins que necesitas en el [catálogo de plugins de Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding).

Answer (score 1):

puedes crear una función que se active cuando se le da click al boton, luego usar los metodos de "addTo()" y "remove()" para adicionar y remover el marcador. Te sugiero leer la documentación, hay varios metodos y eventos para cada elemento de un mapa con Leaflet.